# Android - swipe to flip card

Tags: android, animation, android-cardview, flip

I want to flip a card view (show the different layout for front/back) using a swipe gesture (swiping from left to right).

Is there a way to achieve this? All examples that I managed to find are using click functionality (on a button, view that is being flipped, etc.) but not a swipe.

Comment: Did you check this library - https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView

Comment: Yes, I checked, but that library has only flipOnTouch property, and that doesn't suit me.